# Why shearing coefficients multiplying by y?

Tags: transformations, projections, affine-transformations

We know that shear is transformation that distorts the shape of the object. Shear relative to X-axis that is $y=0$ line can be written as:
$x'=x+sh_x.y, y'=y$
My question is why $sh_x$ is multiplying by $y,$why not any other constant ?  I want to understand intuition behind this. Every book, website don't mention any reason.

Comment: This question is an exact copy from another network site. See [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286702/why-shearing-multiplying-with-y). Closing here to avoid further scattering of information.

Answer (score 1):

A shear can be thought of as an affine transformation that turns a square into a parallelogram:

[image: An undeformed units square, with points a, b, c, and d identified, and the square after deformation by a shear, with points a', b', c', and d' identified.]

Note that the spacing of points at the same x-position are unchanged by the transformation; the distance between $a$ and $b$ is the same as between $a'$ and $b'$, and the distance $cd$ is the same as the distance $c'd'$. What has changed is that each x-layer has been shifted to the right, relative to the layers below it; the x-axis itself is unshifted. This means that the image of a point $(x,y)$ must be at the same y-level, i.e. $y' = y$, and be shifted to the right, i.e. $x' = x + d$ for some $d$. In fact, $d$ must be a function of $y$ that increases as $y$ increases, since each layer is to the right of the layers below it.

The point $c = (0,1)$ has been shifted to $c' = (sh_x,1)$. Since the shear is an affine transformation, the vertical line from the origin to $c$ has been transformed to a straight line from the origin to $c'$. The point $a = (0,0.5)$, halfway along the line to $c$, must therefore be transformed to a point halfway along the line to $c'$, i.e. $(0.5 \times sh_x, 0.5)$. In general, the distance $d$ from the y-axis to the transformed y-axis must just be $sh_x \times y$, or

$$
x \mapsto x + sh_x \times y, 
y \mapsto y.
$$

Comment: "In fact, d must be a function of y that increases "-- why?

Comment: @User4567: The shift can't depend on x, because the distance between points with the same y-coordinate is the same, i.e. $|f(x + dx, y) - f(x,y)| = dx$. But the shift increases as the y coordinate increases (as, I think, is obvious from the diagram). So it must be an increasing function of y.