# 3D shearing w. r. t $x$-axis

Tags: 3d, transformations, projections

Shearing in $X$ axis is achieved by using the following shearing equations-

$X_{new} = X_{old}, 
Y_{new} = Y_{old} + Sh_y × X_{old}, 
Z_{new} = Z_{old} + Sh_z × X_{old}.$

My question is during $Y_{new}$ and $Z_{new}$ calculations why $Sh_y,Sh_z$ is multiplying with $X_{old}$ respectively, why not any other constant? Every books, websites mention just formula not the reason.

Can anyone give pictorial representations how shearing is happening with explanation.

Comment: Science and mathematics only answer the question how, they do not answer why. Do you mean to use "reasoning" instead of "reason". But really this is just a slope, further away gets moved more. It would be easier if you already  understood linear algebra because the linear algebra transform gives a better general explanation than the function one which quite frankly is just adding known functions together.

Comment: This is exactly the same as [your other question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/12276/why-shearing-coefficients-multiplying-by-y), just with the axes switched around. And someone has already kindly made you a pictorial representation there.

Comment: @Nathan Not same, his answer is unsatisfactory and it is 3D shearing which totally different from 2D..

Comment: It is a fine answer. If you are still having trouble understanding, you could ask some follow up questions, or spend some more time thinking about it on your own. And 3D shearing is not totally different. It is pretty much the same thing. If you have understood the 2D case, you will have no trouble understanding 3D.

Comment: @Nathan It's was better answer w. r. t me. He was not exaplined mathematically. He discussed much unnecessary things like any other websites.

Comment: That answer looks plenty mathematical to me. And you asked for help building the intuition behind it. We can't know what is intuitive to you or not, or what is "unnecessary" to you. You may need to work on asking more clearly for what you need, rather than writing off answers you can't understand right away. We can't read your mind to find where the sticking point in understanding is.

Comment: @Nathan he isn't exaplained behind reason of this statement  **In fact, d must be a function of y** which is my intended demand, but has discussed too much unnecessary things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shearing coefficients multiplying by y?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/12276/why-shearing-coefficients-multiplying-by-y)

Comment: Closing for being a duplicate, not only on this site, but also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291739/3d-shearing-w-r-t-x-axis) where you already got plenty of answers